# Haskell do-notation has no equivalent for-comprehension in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, for-comprehension, do-notation

Consider the following Haskell code that builds a balanced binary tree:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty

build :: Int -> [(Tree Char, Int)] 
build n = do
  let k = (n - 1) `div` 2
  (l, i) <- build k
  (r, j) <- build (n - k - 1)
  let h = i + j + 1
  (Node 'x' l r, h) : [(Node 'x' r l, h) | abs (i - j) == 1]
```

Attempting to convert it to Scala 3 yields the following:

```
enum Tree[+A]:
  case Empty
  case Node(value: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A])

object Tree:

  def build(n: Int): List[(Tree[Char], Int)] =
    val k = (n - 1) / 2
    for
      (l, i) <- build(k)
      (r, j) <- build(n - k - 1)
      h = i + j + 1
      xs = if math.abs(i - j) == 1
           then List((Node('x', r, l), h))
           else Nil
    yield (Node('x', l, r), h)
```

**The Scala code, however, doesn't compile.** This is because `yield` wants to return a tuple, not a list of tuples.

In Haskell, the do-notation can use `return` (or `pure`) to "lift" a value to the enclosing monad, or if no `return` is used, the value of the last expression must already be the type of the enclosing monad. In Scala, `yield` is analogous to `return`, but the option to not use `yield` translates into a `foreach` that doesn't return anything.

The Scala code can be written as follows to return a list instead, but it's not pretty as when for-comprehension is used.

```
val k = (n - 1) / 2
build(k).flatMap((l, i) =>
  build(n - k - 1).flatMap { (r, j) =>
    val h = i + j + 1
    val xs =
      if math.abs(i - j) == 1
      then List((Node('x', r, l), h))
      else Nil
    (Node('x', l, r), h) :: xs
  }
)
```

I also attempted to nest the for-comprehensions, but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax.

My question is this: Is it possible to use for-comprehension to obtain the equivalent of the Haskell code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Scala is a bit rusty but I think you'd have to write

```
object Tree:
  def build(n: Int): List[(Tree[Char], Int)] =
    val k = (n - 1) / 2
    for
      (l, i) <- build(k)
      (r, j) <- build(n - k - 1)
      h = i + j + 1
      x <- (Node('x', l, r), h) :: (
             if math.abs(i - j) == 1
             then List((Node('x', r, l), h))
             else Nil)
    yield x
```

Comment: This does work, I should've thought about this. The prepend to the list is just building up the final list, so, yielding on each element of the list makes sense. Thanks!